# Schedule disable/enable in SQL Reporting on Azure when not being used

Tags: reporting-services, azure, azure-sql-database

Since Microsoft has decided to charge from July 31st for SQL reporting is there anyway I can schedule a disable/enable everyday just so the hours/cost doesn't rack up when its not getting used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unfortunately, you can't as of the current release. you may want to add your vote for that feature at: http://www.mygreatwindowsazureidea.com/forums/169380-business-analytics-sql-reporting